# Get client's signature from the Hyperledger Fabric block and verify it

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, x509certificate, private-key, public-key, ecdsa

In Hyperledger Fabric, the client signs a transaction using the private key. I am trying to find this signature from the block and verify the sign using client's public key.

Code to fetch signature in nodejs:

```
let getBlockByTX = await blockContract.evaluateTransaction("GetBlockByTxID", channelName, txId);
const resultJson = BlockDecoder.decode(getBlockByTX);
let signaturePRVKey =resultJson.data.data[0].signature;
```

Output:

```
signaturePRVKey in base64 format
MEUCIQC330iICU/FP1XCIsYIHl4e6ytuS9niir/J7lZ5J5kYegIgF0zvjObCXMnrJfA+QXzIbbuJfJfx0ld+Wv6GknSX3fg=

signaturePRVKey in hex format
3045022100b7df4888094fc53f55c222c6081e5e1eeb2b6e4bd9e28abfc9ee56792799187a0220174cef8ce6c25cc9eb25f03e417cc86dbb897c97f1d2577e5afe86927497ddf8
```

I want to know, is **signaturePRVKey** giving me the correct signature?

For Signature(signaturePRVKey) verification using **jsrsasign** library:

```
const data = [
    "p1","Alice","F","alice@gmail.com","02156874652",
]

var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({ "alg": "SHA256withECDSA" });
sig.init(certificatePEM);

sig.updateString(data)
var isValid = sig.verify(signaturePRVKey)
console.log(isValid)
```

**signaturePRVKey** verification using client Certificate return false. Please Let me know how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlockDecoder unpacks the raw protocol buffer message structure of the block into a plain JavaScript object structure. The result you get from it is not in a form that allows you to verify the signature. Bear in mind though that the signature will have already been verified as part of the transaction submit process. If the signature is invalid, the transaction will be rejected.

If you do want to verify the signatures yourself, in the original protocol buffer message structure of the [Block](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/protos.html#common-Block), each element of the Block's `data.data` array is the serialized bytes of an [Envelope](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/protos.html#common-Envelope). The Envelope contains a `signature` property (which you are successfully retrieving) and a `payload` property (which is the serialized bytes of a [Payload](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/protos.html#common-Payload) protocol buffer message). The `signature` is the digital signature of the `payload`. This can be verified using the signer's public key.

Note also that the Payload itself contains within it a [SignatureHeader](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/protos.html#common-SignatureHeader), and the `creator` property of that SignatureHeader contains both the Member Services Provider ID (MSP ID) of the signer and also their `id_bytes`, which will typically be the signer's X.509 certificate in PEM format. The X.509 certificate contains the signer's public key.

If you want to do this signature verification then you need to work directly with the protocol buffer message returned by **GetBlockByTxID**, not the output of BlockDecoder. There are published packages containing the generated language bindings for the Fabric protocol buffer messages that you can use for this purpose:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-protos/

There are examples of these packages being used to unpack Block protocol buffer messages in the [off_chain_data](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data) sample:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/off_chain_data/application-typescript/src/blockParser.ts

Comment: I'm not familiar with typeScript. Does BlockDecoder.js do the parsing? If yes then, according to you can **envelopeProto.signature** be verified against **envelopeProto.payload**?

Comment: TypeScript is JavaScript with typing so the actual code should read exactly like JavaScript. The Envelope has two fields: `payload` and `signature`. The `signature` is the digital signature of the `payload`. You will need the signer's public key to verify the signature. If you don't already have it, it is contained within the signer's X.509 certificate, as described above.